# How does code formatting work?

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

I edited a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44019594/revisions) and noticed something weird.

What I did was selected code block (as it was not formatted) and used <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> for code formatting.

What happened is

```
public void testMethod(Map settings) {
```

changed to

```
public void testMethod(Map<String, ?> settings) {
```

How was *generic* (`?`, etc.) added?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `<String, ?>` was there, but wasn't visible because it triggered HTML. After it was formatted, it's no longer interpreted as HTML code, and it becomes visible.

Comment: This. Visible in the original source: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/91e6a158-7838-440b-92fc-16b9c0fccccf/view-source